# Azure DevOps - Static Web Apps failing within a Pipeline with container job

Tags: docker, azure-devops

```
parameters:
  - name: App_VariableGroup
    type: string
    default: my-defaults
    values:
      - my-defaults

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

container: ubuntu:20.04

variables:
  - group: ${{ parameters.App_VariableGroup }}

steps:
- checkout: self
  submodules: true
- script: | 
    echo Hello, world! \n 
    ls -al
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
  inputs:
    app_location: $(publish_path)
    api_location: ''
    output_location: ''
    skip_app_build: true
    azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(swa_deployment_token)
```

This code is failing with "container: ubuntu:20.04" and give the following error:

```
##[warning]Environment variable AGENT_CONTAINERMAPPING is a multiline string and cannot be added to the build environment.
/usr/bin/bash /__w/_tasks/AzureStaticWebApp_18aad896-e191-4720-88d6-8ced4806941a/0.200.0/launch-docker.sh
/__w/_tasks/AzureStaticWebApp_18aad896-e191-4720-88d6-8ced4806941a/0.200.0/launch-docker.sh: line 1: docker: command not found
##[error]Error: The process '/usr/bin/bash' failed with exit code 127
Finishing: AzureStaticWebApp
```

But the Task: AzureStaticWebApp@0 works fine with just the vmImage and no container.

I remember there is docker:dind concept that I used in gitlab-cicd but could anyone advice on what is going wrong here please?

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems is that you need docker installed on your container. You may use [this](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-docker-on-ubuntu-20-04) guide for how to do that.

However, there is another issue which seems to be a bug in the task itself causing it to fail, possibly related to not being able to load the **AGENT_CONTAINERMAPPING** environment variable. I ran into this bug myself with an Ubuntu container loaded with docker and other tools specific to my pipeline.

Please reference [this bug](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/16275) I submitted to the *Microsoft/azure-pipelines-task* project for more details and to include your voice.

Comment: thanks but I guess trying to run docker inside docker on any of the Azure managed container services will not work, since we need to mount the /var/run/docker.sock to be able to create container within docker-in-docker. If Microsoft allows that, then the container we create will get privileged access to the host & other containers running on that host. Thus it will become a security issue.